# Переход от Jquery на чистый JS($(this))

Tags: javascript, jquery

Меня попросили избавиться от Jquery и написать весь код на js, проблема в том, что я не очень понимаю как мне заменить `$(this)`. Например

```
$('.tag').click(function(){
  $(this)...etc
})
```

Все заменить легко на `QuerySelect` и `addEventListener`, а вот `$(this)` не понятно.

Comment: this так и останется this, только без доллара со скобочками. Он у вас по каким-то причинам не работает?

Answer (score 0):

```
let tag = document.querySelector('.tag');

tag.addEventListener('click', () => {
    console.log(tag);
});
```

И если элемент не один

```
let tag = document.querySelectorAll('.tag');

tag.forEach(item => {
    item.onclick = () => {
        console.log(item);
    }
});
```

Answer (score -2):

Просто нужно было сделать следующим образом:

```
test.addEventListener('click', (event) => {
    console.log(event.target);
    //это и будет объектом this
});
```

Comment: @VladiuslavKim а теперь кликните по элементу, который является дочерним для `.tag` и посмотрите результат...

Comment: @PavelMayorov эх, не заметил что стрелочная функция. Разные, но при отсутствии дочерних элементов (вроде про них в вопросе речь не шла - хотя и обратное не утверждалось, да) должны совпасть

Comment: @Regent как показывает опыт, даже если изначально там не было дочерних элементов - однажды они внезапно появятся

Comment: @PavelMayorov согласен. С `event.currentTarget` проблем вроде быть не должно?

Comment: @Regent да, с currentTarget проблем быть не должно